# Firebase Cloud Messaging not showing notification bar when app is open

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to test my app with sending the notification via console in firebase cloud messaging, But when my app in the foreground or still running. The notification do not show in the device and the log in the firebase messaging service is triggered.

But when i destroy my app, the notification work nicely.

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/eclass_logo1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/eclass_logo1"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">


        <service
            android:name=".myFirebaseInstanceTokenID">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Tugas" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".NilaiActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BaseActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MateriActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".NilaiDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PesertaActivity"></activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

This my firebasemessagingservice

```
public class myFirebaseInstanceTokenID extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingServce";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Tidak ada Data");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're observing is is how notification type messages work on Android.  When your app is in the foreground, you will not see a notification in the tray.

Please [read the documentation on handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) to understand what to expect.  Especially see the "in summary" box that tells you how message handling is different between foreground and background states of your app.  Not that when your app is in the foreground, you can only expect that your message will be seen in `onMessageReceived`.  You can construct a notification there yourself, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation will not show a notification when your application is in the foreground.  You will need to handle `onMessageReceived(...)` yourself and create and display a notification as needed.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

> Firebase notifications behave differently depending on the
>   foreground/background state of the receiving app. If you want
>   foregrounded apps to receive notification messages or data messages,
>   you’ll need to write code to handle the onMessageReceived callback.
>   For an explanation of the difference between notification and data
>   messages, see Message types.