# Show Heads-up notification when app is background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, heads-up-notifications

#### I want to appear **Heads Up Notification** When My android app is **background**.

When my app is open, Heads Up Notification appears but if the app is background or closed, it just showing on the normal status bar.

I tried on many other resources and read also in stack overflow similar questions.

But I didn't get a useful solution yet. Is it possible to show Heads Up Notification even when the app is background?

Comment: Yes, most heads-up notifications come from apps in the background.  You should post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has two types of messages:

- Notification messages, which are delivered to your application code if it is active, and are handled by the system when your app is not active.
- Data messages, which are always delivered to your application code.

From what you're describing it sounds like you're sending a `notification` message. If you always want your application code to handle the message, so that you control how it is displayed, you'll want to send a `data` message instead.

For more on messages types, see:

- the [Firebase documentation on message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)
- [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)
- [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging not showing notification bar when app is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372511/firebase-cloud-messaging-not-showing-notification-bar-when-app-is-open)

Comment: Great Documentation!.Thanks for the answer . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase. This link helped me a lot